# How can i append to PDF file in Node-RED?

Tags: node-red

I'm looking for solution on how can I append to a PDF file. The output 'file' of HTML-PDF node generate a new file every time I insert new line. The output "buffer"  /"stream" save only the first insert.

Is it possible to append PDF file in Node-RED?

And thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

PDFs don't work that way, they are basically a "printer" output, so effectively have a header with the total length at the start.

If you want to append to the end you will need to buffer the content in the Node-RED context and send the whole thing to the HTML-PDF node each time.